# How to query max to min in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to query from max entry to min entry in a topic. Such that:

**models.py**

```
class Topic(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=140, unique=True, verbose_name=_("Title"))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_("Created at"))
```

**And other model is :**

```
class Entry(models.Model):

    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, verbose_name=_("Topic"))
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Content"))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,verbose_name=_("Created at"))
```

Firstly, I want to filter only today's entries from **Topic.py**. Is that correct? :

```
def get_topic_today(self):
    return self.filter(date=datetime.date.today()).order_by('title')
```

And also I want to query popular topic max to min. I think we can use select_related with reverse foreign keys from entry to topic models. But  I can not do it. For example, the topic which has most entry number must be first and going on lowest.

Comment: What is self? Does that code do what you want it to?

Comment: class TopicQuerySet(QuerySet): Sorry I forgot to write class. I just want to filter enrty only in today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter a DateTimeField to a specific day, you can use the [`__day` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#day).

```
def get_topic_today(self):
    return self.filter(created_at__day=datetime.date.today()).order_by('title')
```

To get the count of a related model, use the [`Count` annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#id7), then do a descending sort on it:

```
Topic.objects.annotate(entry_count=Count('entry')).order_by('-entry_count')
```

Comment: `Entry`/`Topic` classes do not have `date` field but `created_at`.

Comment: @Todor Oops! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order popular topic from max entry to min:

```
def get_topic_today(self):
    return self.filter(created_at__date=datetime.date.today()).annotate(entry_count=models.Count('entry_set')).order_by('-entry_count')
```

Answer (score 0):

For min and max dates

```
### please use range for selecting between dates

def get_topic_today(self):
    return self.filter(created_at__range=[min_date, max_date]).order_by('title')

### (or) use greater than or lesser than

def get_topic_today(self):
    return self.filter(created_at__gte=min_date, created_at__lte=max_date).order_by('title')
```